# SimpleMembership tables not being created on remote server (Local works fine) EF MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

I'm trying to extend simplemembership functionality and I have a problem with creating tables and filling them from seed method using update-database.
Local command

```
 update-database
```

creates all tables and fills them properly including webpages_Membership etc. 
When i try to update this on server with this command:

```
  update-database -ConnectionStringName "remote" -Verbose
```

Only tables which were designed by myself are being created and filled.

Heres what i have from server:

```
  PM> update-database -ConnectionStringName "remote" -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Phones'.
Using NuGet project 'Phones'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'databasename' (DataSource: tcp:server,port, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Explicit).
No pending code-based migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201407232047491_AutomaticMigration.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max),
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max),
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max),
    [Email] [nvarchar](max),
    [Balance] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserProfile] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [IMEI] [nvarchar](max),
    [UnlockCode] [nvarchar](max),
    [UserProfile_UserId] [int],
    [Phone_PhoneId] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Orders] PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phones] (
    [PhoneId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Manufacturer] [nvarchar](max),
    [Model] [nvarchar](max),
    [UnlockPrice] [float] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Phones] PRIMARY KEY ([PhoneId])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_UserProfile_UserId] ON [dbo].[Orders]([UserProfile_UserId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_Phone_PhoneId] ON [dbo].[Orders]([Phone_PhoneId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.UserProfile_UserProfile_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserProfile_UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Phones_Phone_PhoneId] FOREIGN KEY ([Phone_PhoneId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Phones] ([PhoneId])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
)
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
[Inserting migration history record]
Running Seed method.
```

And from Local:

```
PM> update-database -Verbose
Using StartUp project 'Phones'.
Using NuGet project 'Phones'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'phones' (DataSource: localhost\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending code-based migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201407232046599_AutomaticMigration.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max),
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max),
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max),
    [Email] [nvarchar](max),
    [Balance] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.UserProfile] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [IMEI] [nvarchar](max),
    [UnlockCode] [nvarchar](max),
    [UserProfile_UserId] [int],
    [Phone_PhoneId] [int],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Orders] PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phones] (
    [PhoneId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Manufacturer] [nvarchar](max),
    [Model] [nvarchar](max),
    [UnlockPrice] [float] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Phones] PRIMARY KEY ([PhoneId])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_UserProfile_UserId] ON [dbo].[Orders]([UserProfile_UserId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_Phone_PhoneId] ON [dbo].[Orders]([Phone_PhoneId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.UserProfile_UserProfile_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserProfile_UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserProfile] ([UserId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Orders_dbo.Phones_Phone_PhoneId] FOREIGN KEY ([Phone_PhoneId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Phones] ([PhoneId])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
)
BEGIN TRY
    EXEC sp_MS_marksystemobject 'dbo.__MigrationHistory'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
[Inserting migration history record]
Running Seed method.
```

My Class with seed method:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Phones.Models.UsersContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

        }

        protected override void Seed(Phones.Models.UsersContext context)
        {
            if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(
                   "DefaultConnection",
                   "UserProfile",
                   "UserId",
                   "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            if (!Roles.RoleExists("Administrator"))
                Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
            if (!Roles.RoleExists("User"))
                Roles.CreateRole("User");

            if (!WebSecurity.UserExists("Admin"))
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(
                    "Admin",
                    "pass",
                    new { FirstName = "testname", LastName = "testsurname", Email = "email@email.com", Balance = 0, Enabled = true });

            if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("Admin").Contains("Administrator"))
                Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "Admin" }, new[] { "Administrator" });
        }
    }
```

Here's my UsersContext class:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Best Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using visual studio command prompt on the remote server?

If you open the visual studio command prompt (in start, type visual studio command prompt it should come up).

then in the command prompt type:

```
Aspnet_regsql.exe
```

This will open up a programme that is designed to create the membership schema for asp.net websites. You can connect remotely to your database from this application aswell.

When the application opens:

- click configure SQL Server for Application Services
- Hit next and you'll be prompted on whether you want to connect remotely or not.

[image: Remote connection example]

- Enter your credentials then hit next. You'll get a settings summary of the database you're connecting to, and the server it is on. Check this is all ok then hit next.
- Follow the instructions and it'll install the necessary ASP_ databases used for membership (ROLES ect).

Answer (score 0):

Using the update-database command in this manner is really intended as a short cut during development and not intended to be used for setting up remote servers for test or production.  For a remote server use the script parameter with the update-database command to create the sql script to either create or update an existing database and then run the script on that server.